# Windows Phone timer under locked screen

Tags: timer, windows-phone-8, locked

I try to make a Windows Phone app which plays sounds to help you fall asleep. I use SoundEffect class so that I can mix multiple sound files. The certification requirements says

> "An app can play media in the background while it is running even when
>   its primary function is not related to music or video. An app that
>   plays music, audio, or sound effects must meet the following
>   requirements:" "The SoundEffect class must not be used to play a
>   continuous background music track in an app."
>    So if the SoundEffect class plays continuos music under locked screen is ok, right?

I made a timer with DispatcherTimer class, so that the user can set the time when sounds stop, so the battery won't go dead. But the certification requirements says

> "All apps that run under a locked screen must stop any UI updates,
>   active timers, and other non-critical processing when notified that
>   the screen is locked."
>   So I can't use that, because my app has to be able to run under locked screen. What can I do to stop the music playing after a time interval or at a set time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > **and other non-critical processing**

Turning off the music is a key feature of your app, and therefore is a critical processing.

That said, since the DispatcherTimer has a strong dependance on the UI, I don't know if it will run properly under the lock screen. You should use a classical timer instead, or even better, just a thread with a `Thread.Sleep` instruction.

For instance, if you must stop the music two hours after the screen is locked, start a thread in the `Obscured` event and make it sleep for two hours:

```
private void TurnOffMusic()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 60 * 2); // Sleep for two hours
    // Turn off the music
}
```